# Why is my PHP script generating "Failed opening 'XmlWriter.class.php' for inclusion" errors, and why does the script still seem to work?

Tags: php

I use the following PHP script to pull records from a database and output them as XML. I have remote free server with MySql and php.

This is my php script:

```
@date_default_timezone_set("GMT"); 

include('XmlWriter.class.php');

$conn = mysql_connect("...") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("....", $conn);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `IngredientDB`';
$res = mysql_query($sql);

$xml = new XMLWriter();

$xml->openURI("php://output");
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->setIndent(true);

$xml->startElement('ingredients');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $xml->startElement("ingredient");

    $xml->writeElement('rowid', $row['rowid']);
    $xml->writeElement('RecipeID', $row['RecipeID']);
    $xml->writeElement('Ingredient', $row['Ingredient']);
    $xml->writeElement('Quantity', $row['Quantity']);

    $xml->endElement();
}

$xml->endElement();

$xml->flush();
exit;
```

The script generates the following errors. The funny thing is that after those errors, the script still displays the data from the DB.

> **Warning**:  include(XmlWriter.class.php) [function.include]:
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/srv/disk8/925206/www/foodrecipedb.host-
> ed.net    /ingredient.php** on line **5**
>
> **Warning**:  include() [function.include]: 
> Failed opening 'XmlWriter.class.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/share/pear') in 
> **/srv/disk8    /925206/www/foodrecipedb.host-ed.net/ingredient.php** on line **5**

Comment: `xmlWriter.class.php` is not found in the PHP `include_path`. Make sure the file exists somewhere in the include path, or in the same directory as this script.

Comment: Near duplicate of [Class 'PharData' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847013/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning messages (note: they're not errors) tell you what's wrong: PHP couldn't find XmlWriter.class.php. As for why the script works, it's because [XmlWriter](http://php.net/XmlWriter) is defined in an extension, not a separate PHP script, so you don't need to include anything to use it. Removing the include line will stop the warnings.

Comment: Outis thx, I still have a question, I have two tables in my db. I wrote php script for each one to retrieve data. This time when I try to open php in the browser it re-directs me to main page of my hosting server. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: SO is a Q&A site, not a forum. Comments aren't meant for discussions. If you have a new question, post it as such. First gather enough information to understand and reproduce the issue, then search to see if the issue is already covered by an existing question. If you can't find one, create a new [question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints), including the information necessary to reproduce the issue but with any extraneous information removed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
include('XmlWriter.class.php');
```

The error is that this PHP file cannot be found. But since the rest of your page works OK without it, it is probably already being loaded (or autoloaded) somewhere else, which makes this line unnecessary.